# How to change the index property in Azure SQL Database

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, azure-sql-database

I could change the index property in one of the table from **Unique, Non-Clustered, Filtered** to **Non-Unique, Non-Clustered** in SQL Server on local machine. But I could **NOT** find any property in accessing Azure SQL Database via SQL Server MAnagement Studio.

How do I change in via TSQL?

Comment: [`CREATE INDEX ... WITH (DROP_EXISTING = ON)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/sql/t-sql/statements/create-index-transact-sql#drop_existing-clause). Going from unique to non-unique isn't a simple toggle (although conceptually it could be); the index will need to be recreated.

Comment: 'although conceptually it could be' not the way indexes are implemented in SQL Server.  Non-unique indexes always contain the table's clustered index key columns.  So basically you are _adding_ key columns to the index when you make it non-unique.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft: *all* non-clustered indexes contain the clustered key columns, no? Uniqueness doesn't matter for that. Non-unique clustered indexes just also have a uniquifier, but that doesn't apply to non-clustered indexes. Primary key != clustered index != unique index (they can coincide, but need not).

Comment: Non unique non clustered indexes have the clustered index key columns as key columns.  Unique non clustered indexes have them as included columns.

Comment: Is it possible to a change this indexing via sql server management studio?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After upgrading to latest SSMS 17.9.1, still not be able to change this via this tool So the query will drop first and then recreated:

```
DROP INDEX [IX_ClubApplicationUser_LastModifiedBy] ON [dbo].[ClubApplicationUser]
GO

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_ClubApplicationUser_LastModifiedBy] ON [dbo].[ClubApplicationUser]
(
    [LastModifiedBy] ASC
)
GO
```

This will change into **NONCLUSTERED, NON-UNIQUE as well as NON-FILTERED.**

The reason we change as the **"Code First"** approach in **.NET CORE 2** generated automatically this type of index.